# Filtering GeoJson data in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I've been tring to filter multiple checkboxes in a geojson. Im using leaflet with the leaflet ajax plug in. Im a begginer at this.

I put this code on the buttons

```
            $("#btnFltGeralALL").click(function(){
                $("input[name=fltGeral]").prop('checked',true);
            });
            
            $("#btnFltGeralNONE").click(function(){
                $("input[name=fltGeral]").prop('checked',false);
            });
            
            $("#btnFltGeral").click(function(){
                arDoencasEnd = [];
                doencas.refresh();
            });
```

And this function:

```
function fltDoencas (json){
                var arProjectFilters=[];
                $("input[name=fltGeral]").each(function(){
                    if(this.checked) {
                        arProjectFilters.push(this.value);
                    }
                });
                var atributos = json.properties;
                switch (atributos.type){
                    case "1835":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('1835')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "1836":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('1836')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "1839":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('1839')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "F":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('F')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "M":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('M')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "Disenteria":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('Disenteria')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "Tísica":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('Tísica')>=0);
                        break;
                    case "N/A":
                        return (arProjectFilters.indexOf('N/A')>=0);
                        break;
                 }
            };
```

and this is the object

```
doencas = L.geoJSON.ajax('data/Doencas.geojson',{filter:fltDoencas, pointToLayer:returnDoencas}).addTo(meumapa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
function fltDoencas (json){
    var arProjectFilters=[];
    $("input[name=fltGeral]").each(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            arProjectFilters.push(this.value);
        }
    });
    var atributos = json.properties;
    if(arProjectFilters.indexOf(atributos.type)>=0){
        return true;
    }
                   
};
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76089895/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).